# Can you explain the difference? And give some context?

Tags: american-english, british-english

Let's say you are planning to update your phone number that has been registred with an organization.

I am not sure this is the number that i want to **change to**.

I am not sure this is the number that i want to **change from**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only the usual difference between "to" and "from".

"From" is the starting point. "To" is the destination.  So "the number I want to change from" is the old number, and "... change to" is the new number.